# Report styles in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2013

I have an assignment that says to create a stepped report in Concourse style in Access 2013. However, I can't find a place where I can select the style, and when I follow Report Wizard instructions online, the Wizard on my computer completely skips the step about styles.

Comment: Does "Design view" say anything to you? ;)

Comment: I can't post this as an answer because of potential "web rot", and it's too long for me to break down today because I have my own work to get done, but [this PDF file](http://webs.wofford.edu/whisnantdm/training/Access2007/Access%202007%20Lesson%2003%20-%20Reporting.pdf) will explain everything you've mentioned, and how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to notify your instructor that they will need to update their assignment since it is slightly out of date. The "Styles" option in the Report Wizard dialog in Access was removed from the product starting in Access 2010. You'll see it in Access 2007 which is probably when your assignment was first drafted. In Access 2010, 2013, and 2016, there is no Styles option in the dialog because it was removed in favor of using the newer themes for reports and forms.